# Is "specific" an antonym of "unspecified“?

Tags: antonyms

Is "specific" an antonym of "unspecified“?

I ask because in some cases I feel it is so, but not always.

Comment: no, it's *specified*. *specific* is an antonym of *unspecific!* :)

Comment: I wouldn't ask this question. What you said just goes without saying.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng I think something that is *specified* is something stated *specifically*. In this sense, something *specific* is something exact and usually it has been *specified* in the context, where something *unspecified* is something that hasn't yet been stated specifically. So they're closely related, but I think I wouldn't call them antonyms.

Comment: Quite so, but I still have some dubious thoughts. I just cannot put them into words. @Damkerng T

Comment: @Maulik - Many words have more than one antonym. (Quick! What's the antonym of _light_? Is it _dark_? Or _heavy_?). This is a legitimate question. I believe _specific_ and _unspecified_ can function as antonyms in certain contexts. _The customer mentioned that there were several specific/unspecified problems with our prototype_.

Comment: @J.R. in that sense *specific* could be opposite to *general*, *obvious*, *natural*, *default* and so on! Too broad to answer.

Comment: It's not too broad to answer. Too broad would be something like, "What are all the antonyms of _specific_?"

Comment: *Unspecific* is more common in the UK, while *nonspecific* is more common in the US (judging by COCA and BNC results).

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. They have opposing implications but "a specific item" can be "unspecified". For instance, you may be required to insert Item A into Slot B. "Item A" is a specific item in the instructions but what "Item A" corresponds to in your bag of parts may be unspecified.

By corollary, an unspecific item can be specified. "Insert a rod into Slot B". Which rod? It specified to insert a rod, not a tube or something else, but it left unspecified which rod.

Anyway, "yes and no" is about as specific an answer you'll get here.

Comment: I have similar thoughts about it. You made it clear for me.